# Writing Html Code in HtmlString.Append with referencing Css class

Tags: c#, vb.net

At the above code which genarating html code like this.i can't see  css style on web browser.
How can i reference css style to the this string statement ? It was used this method to display datas bu another developer instead of binding gridview.
Thanks.

*sHTMLString.Append("<'TD Width='10%' align='center' class='uedasOutputText'>")*

Comment: Your current sample is not enough to provide any reasonable suggestion. Please consider showing result HTML output so it is clear what portion of the string is lost (or if you just can't get CSS to pick up the class).

Comment: I fixed it thanks.The problem was adding css class to the table tag.I couldn't see.That's my fault.